# Property does not exist on type 'never[], What is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

all,
I'm new in the theme React+Typescript.
In my example code, I get json object and going to print one property onto the console. The data from the server came successfully. But by the attempt make the output I receive the message "**Property 'album' does not exist on type 'never[]'**", though all the types are defined. Where am I wrong? Should I some way initialize the 'gallery' in the state?

```
    import React, { Component, Props } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const API = 'http://www.mydomain/testapi/';
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'test.php';


type Image = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  title: string,
  date: string,
  size: number
}

type Album = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  path: string,
  images: Image[]
}


interface State {
 jsonFromServer: string,
 isLoading: boolean,
 errorMsg: string,
 buttonClicked: boolean,
 gallery:Album[]
}


class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    errorMsg: '',
    buttonClicked: false,
    jsonFromServer: "",
    gallery:[] 
    }

  getInfo() {

    this.setState({ isLoading: true, buttonClicked: true });
    axios.get(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
      .then(result => this.setState({
        gallery: result.data.gallery,
        isLoading: false,
        jsonFromServer: result.data

      }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        errorMsg: error.message,
        isLoading: false
      }));
  }

  render() {
    .....
    if (this.state.buttonClicked) {
      this.state.galerie.length > 0 ? console.log('=>', this.state.gallery.album.id) : '';
    }

 ......
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You define `state` but you don't specify it's type. Typescript will thus infer the type of `state` based on the initialization. Since `galerie` is an array but has no elements the best and safest type typescript can infer is `never[]`

The solution is to annotate the `state` member:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state:State  = {
    isLoading: false,
    errorMsg: '',
    buttonClicked: false,
    jsonFromServer: "",
    gallery:[] 
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me but I don't understand why. You mentioned _"Since galerie is an array but has no elements the best and safest type typescript can infer is never[]"_, I can understand that has no elements since state initialized with empty, but why typescript infer that since the state interface define galery as an Album that also has one interface with its types specified? Why he uses never instead the types specified in the interface? What means _"annotate the state member"_ (besides the code modification)?

Answer (score 0):

Your gallery is an array & you're trying to access it like an object. Try this render method instead:

```
  render() {
    .....
    if (this.state.buttonClicked) {
      this.state.galerie.length > 0 ? console.log('=>', this.state.gallery!.album.id) : ''; //it should work now
    }

 ......
  }
```